# How to Break a Loop on Continuously Clicked Button

Tags: android

I am turning a String Array into String items to be shown like separated text or loaded by Picasso.

The problem is when the array ends, it loads the MainActivity again. I need to break it at the last click.

I tried

```
if(no == strNo) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but it proceeds for only two positions in the Array and stops again

```
int i;
int no = 0;
int strNo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    Intent data = getIntent();

    String nameItem = data.getExtras().getString("NameItem");
    final String StrArray[] = nameItem.split(",");

    for (i = 0; i < StrArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(StrArray[i]);

        strNo = StrArray.length;
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textArray);

        //  text.setText(StrArray[0]);

        buNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu_next);
        /* web =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
           web.loadUrl(StrArray[0]);
           web.setInitialScale(100);
        */
        Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(ImageActivity.this).load(StrArray[0]).fit().centerInside().into(Img);

        buNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                no++;
                //   text.setText(StrArray[no]);
                Picasso.with(ImageActivity.this).load(StrArray[no]).fit().centerInside().into(Img);

                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about what you are doing? Based on what I see, you are looping through a string array and setting the same button and image view with the looped items until you reach the `break` in the loop, which stops the loop entirely.

Comment: i am using split to split an array to String which setText onClick inside the main loop.

Comment: Are you wanting to programmatically click the button on each loop?

Comment: yes
repeating the same action of the button click but loading different object from the array 

eg. Ahmed, Mohamed,Mostafa,Darwish,..
i will get these objects from firebase database and retrieve it to my app as one object and split it inside my app

Comment: So not programmatically? You are wanting the button, for every user press, to load the next item in `StrArray` to `Img` with Picasso? If so, then this method will not work because you keep overwriting the button's onClickListener to use the latest item in `StrArray` when the button is clicked.

Comment: OK thank you 
Would you advise me for how could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this since `no=0` it should run up to `< strNo` and you also try to increment the no after using it as below ,

```
 buNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           if(no <strNo){       
           Picasso.with(ImageActivity.this).load(StrArray[no]).fit().centerInside ().into(Img);

           no++;
         }else{    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }
           }


   });
```

Hope it helps.